# Side navbar not responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to make a scroll-able bootstrap side nav that is fully responsive.
I have searched for every possible way in different links and sites but I am not achieving what I want.

So here is my problem:
I want a side nav that is full-responsive in every media screens. It is behaving normal in larger screens, but in small screens the offset that I had set to the side nav does not match and I don't think it is possible to add offset in every single media screens through jquery. So, please can anyone help me with this problem? Below is the link for the JSFiddle that I created and this is the jquery that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myNav").affix({
    offset: {
      top: 1100,
      bottom: ($('.other').outerHeight(true)) + 445
    }
  });

  $("#myNav").on('affixed.bs.affix');
});

$('#myNav a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheela_paudel/yncauzo7/1/

Thank you in advance for your help. It means a lot. I also wanted to ask if we could give offset value in percentage rather than pixels.

Comment: upto how much media screen do you need side nav ?

Comment: I don't want  side nav below   media-screen 767px. It would be great if I get the side nav above media screen 767px .

Comment: You must provide the code, here, that shows the problem. Links to third-party sites don't help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes in JS to set the offset from top and bottom by using class or ID

```
$(function(){
    var stickyElement   = '#myScrollspy',  
     bottomElement   = '.other'; 
     if($( stickyElement ).length){
     $( stickyElement ).each(function(){
     var fromTop = $( this ).offset().top, 
     fromBottom = $( document ).height()-($( this ).offset().top + $( this ).outerHeight()),
     stopOn = $( document ).height()-( $( bottomElement ).offset().top)+($( this ).outerHeight() - $( this ).height()); 
      if( (fromBottom-stopOn) > 200 ){
      $( this ).css('width', $( this ).width()).css('top', 0).css('position', '');
      $( this ).affix({
      offset: { 
       bottom: stopOn
       }
        }).on('affix.bs.affix', function(){ $( this ).css('top', 0).css('position', ''); });
           }
         $( window ).trigger('scroll'); 
       }); 
       }
      });
```

You can overcome with it using Jquery

[you can see it in this link](https://jsfiddle.net/sus_hill/mx6etqwk/10/)

`var stickyElement   = '#myScrollspy', 
bottomElement   = '.other';`

just give the class name or ID you want in these 2 lines to get offset from top and bottom.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It worked in smaller screen, screen smaller than 768px but  the side nav appears above the map at 990px

Comment: thank you Sus Hill your edited answer worked for me. Thanks a ton.